Avoiding ambiguity between scalar names and variable names
Lots of hair tearing about unexpected behavior until I landed on:
Do-file:
program drop _all
program define _wtf
 local name  = abbrev(`"`1'"', 12)
 scalar mean  = `="`2'"'
 scalar stat = `="`3'"'
 scalar se = `="`4'"'
 noi: di _newline "mean: " mean "   stat: " stat "   se: " se
 end

local my_name = "abc"
scalar val1 = 1.2
scalar val2 = 2.3
scalar val3 = 3.4 
_wtf "`name'" val1 val2 val3

Results from running the do-file:
. program drop _all

. program define _wtf
  1.  local name  = abbrev(`"`1'"', 12)
  2.  scalar mean  = `="`2'"'
  3.  scalar stat = `="`3'"'
  4.  scalar se = `="`4'"'
  5.  noi: di _newline "mean: " mean "   stat: " stat "   se: " se
  6.  end

. 
. local my_name = "abc"

. scalar val1 = 1.2

. scalar val2 = 2.3

. scalar val3 = 3.4 

. _wtf "`name'" val1 val2 val3

mean: 1.2   stat: 2.3   se: 2

Note the se: 2 in that last output line (instead of se: 3.4).
I have the cure2 data set loaded (via webuse cure2). Does this have something to do with se being interpreted as a shortcut for the variable sex in cure2? If so, how can I make explicit in my _wtf program that se refers to the value of the scalar se and is not referring to some variable beginning with those characters?

A reference to scalar(se) should disambiguate.

Thank you @NickCox That resolves the issue of ambiguity, but lordy! That makes code so cumbersome!

The solution is in your own hands, a personal convention to keep scalar and variable names utterly distinct.

@NickCox Yeah, definitely appreciate the explicitness in the namespace there.
